# Error with M values and st_zm function in sf package

Tags: r-sf, r-raster, sentinel2, multipolygons

I have imported a multipolygon shp file containing different forest patches (called 'patch'):
[patch](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hwolE_XJAF8quvVOAwJthwlclEkiVXXw/view?usp=sharing)

Then, I have bricked different Sentinel-2 bands for the same region in a raster called 'SenBel'
data: [SentinelB6-8_patch](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i7hmnAnApvuqyPzn5AZZdrCRcTr0fm1_/view?usp=sharing)
code to brick:

```
    SenBel <- brick(Sentinel_noCl_B6_10m,
                Sentinel_noCl_B7_10m, Sentinel_noCl_B8, nl=3)
```

I would like to calculate the mean reflectance value for each band per patch and add this in the attribute table of the shp file as a new column with the name of the band respectively.
First I created this function:

```
`f1 <- function(raster, column_name) {
    values <- extract(raster, patch)
    mean_values <- unlist(lapply(values, mean, na.rm = TRUE))
    patch[[column_name]] <- mean_values
    }

#Calculate mean values for bands
bands <- c( "B6", "B7", "B8")
for (i in bands) {
  f1(SenBel[[i]], paste0("mean", i))
}`
```

I got following error:
`Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'addAttrToGeom':         geometries containing M not supported by sp use` st_zm(..., what = "M") 
When I tried to use the st_zm function as follows:

```
 `st_zm(patch,drop=TRUE, what="ZM")
 `
```

I kept getting the same error in the function above, as if nothing changed.
If I check for M values, it still states 'TRUE':

```
`contains_M_values <- function(x) {
    coords <- st_coordinates(st_geometry(x))
    dim(coords)[[2]] > 2  # Check if coordinates have more than 2 dimensions (indicating M values)
 }
contains_M_values(patch)
[1] TRUE`
```

Is there another way to solve this problem? I don't fully understand either what M values are or how my shp file contains them.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `M` values are typically 'time' values. Simple Features allow 4 values per coordinate, X, Y, Z (elevation), M (time). Can you reduce & simplify your example to something we can help with? Give us an example data set taht represents your real one?

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for your answer, it is weird that there is a time aspect in the data, I was not aware of that... I added a link to the shp file and a subset of the Sentinel data. Can you access it this way?

Comment: Where does it say that `M` values are typically time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `contains_M_values` does not check whether the m values are gone; use `st_zm` the way you did and then print the object; it should now say `Dimension:     XY` indicating `M` has been removed. Read `?st_coordinates` to find out what that function returns (in addition to vertices, the ring IDs).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! When I just do de st_zm function, the same error still remains...
` Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'addAttrToGeom': geometries containing M not supported by sp
use st_zm(..., what = "M")`
How can I solve this error?

Comment: could you provide the `patch` object, e.g. saved with `save()` as an .rda?

Comment: Hi! I just managed to solve my problem, many thanks for the help! I saved the st_zm as an object and could perform all the functions like extract without problems( a new shp file without M values)
`patch2 --> st_zm(patch, what='ZM')`